# Ubuntu 19.10: grub not shown

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

In the new version 19.10 my grub file is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=4
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Despite this at boot I don't see the grub menu nor does it wait 4 seconds. How I can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` (`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`)...

change:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

then save the file and quit the editor. Next run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

**GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE**

If this option is unset or set to `menu`, then GRUB will display the menu and then wait for the timeout set by `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to expire before booting the default entry. Pressing a key interrupts the timeout.

If this option is set to `countdown` or `hidden`, then, before displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the timeout set by `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to expire. If <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed during that time, it will display the menu and wait for input. If a hotkey associated with a menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu entry immediately. If the timeout expires before either of these happens, it will boot the default entry. In the `countdown` case, it will show a one-line indication of the remaining time.

Comment: Doesn`t work ((( GRUB menu is hidden still

Comment: @Max Your problem may be different. Please start a new question.