# Grub not showing on Ubuntu 19.10 (and only in Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 but, as in [Ubuntu 19.10: grub not shown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182164/ubuntu-19-10-grub-not-shown), Grub is not showing. I tried modifying `/etc/default/grub` and updating (`sudo update-grub`) but this does not work. These are my `/etc/default/grub` file settings:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I also tried with boot-repair (also making the changes in Windows with `bcedit` as specified) but this did not solve the problem. I also tried with Grub Customizer, but the Grub menu is still not showing.

If I reinstall 18.04.3 LTS, Grub shows as usual.

What could be happening?

Comment: Now that you have removed it, we cannot analyze it. Grub normally does not show if only operating system, and if not in same boot mode as Windows or both UEFI, then it would not show. Also 19.10 uses grub 2.04 where 18.04 uses grub 2.02 which may have some differences.

Comment: I think I haven't expressed myself clearly. Sorry for the missing details. I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10 now. To check it was not an internal problem, I removed Ubuntu 19.10 and installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Once I saw this restored group (and that it was not an internal problem I reinstalled Ubuntu 19.10. Like initially, Grub did not show.

Comment: Then run Boot-Repair so we can see details: Use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Here you are. Thanks in advance. [Boot-Info summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fYC2n3TBfC/)

Comment: You show both systems in UEFI boot and Windows in grub menu. Since two boot options it should automatically show. But you also have Windows fast start up on. I thought grub would not add Windows to boot with fast start up on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation You also have a lot of Boot repair logs. You may need to delete old ones, or it will fill ESP.